# jQuery recall plugin chosen after clone not working properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

The code is very simple and can be view on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4pUT/).

Basically, whenever I clone something I need to recall the plugin so it can work on the clone. Unfortunately, it duplicates the info.

```
$(document).on('click', '.add', function(){
    $(".content").append($(".tbl").last().clone());

   // $(".categories").chosen(); this makes duplicate
});
```

With the line commented it simply does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is OK for you, but instead of cloning the whole table, you can clone the `select` itself:

```
$(document).on('click', '.add', function () {
    var $clone = $(".tbl select").last().clone();
    $(".content").append($clone);
    $clone.chosen();
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4pUT/3/)**